# How to identify Agents Private Listing using RETS Server?

Tags: rets

I want to extract agent listing . I used Agent licence number for identifying agents personal listing but the sever is not giving corresponding data.

Answer (score 0):

Many RETS servers are configured only to allow certain fields to be queried in certain combinations, like "Address,Status" or "MLS Area, Status."  It's possible you're not allowed to query all listings under a given listing agent ID.  Please post the raw response from the RETS server and see if this is the problem (the RETS response will usually tell you if you have queried on an invalid column combination).  Another possibility is that you are querying on the wrong value - licence number is generally not the key for an agent - it is usually something like "Listing Agent ID 1" or "Agent MLS ID" or something similar.